# Show Bottom Navigation when Keyboard visible

Tags: android, android-bottomnav

I am Using Fragment where I click on EditText the keyboard visible and I need a Bottom Navigation should comes above the Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

in your manifest

Comment: this should work